How to randomize ship positions in a Battleships game?
I'm writing a battleships game for my college project and I want to randomize the positions of the ships in the beginning of the game. My program has an abstract superclass of Ship which branches out to four different types of other ships:

Carrier (occupies 5 spaces)
Battleship (occupies 4 spaces)
Submarine (occupies 3 spaces)
Patrol Boat (occupies 2 spaces)

Each ship has a different "attack type," hence the use of subclasses.
I'm in the early stages of writing the code right now and feel like I'm facing a few problems

How do I instantiate the ship object efficiently?
So far, it feels as if I need to write 4 different methods to create every ship object and place it on the board

How do I make it so that the ships cannot be in a one block vicinity of each other? (so the ships can't touch each other and cannot overlap each other)


So far, I've only written a method to create a "carrier" ship
private void placeCarrier(char[][] selfGrid, int shipOrientation) {
    int xCor, yCor;
    boolean isShipPlaced = false;

    do {
        // Randomize starting coordinates
        xCor = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        yCor = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;

        // Checking ship orientation and ensuring that the end value is not out of bounds
        if (shipOrientation == VERTICAL && yCor + Carrier.CARRIER_LENGTH < BattleshipSystem.GRID_LENGTH) {
            playerShips[0] = new Carrier(xCor, yCor, xCor, yCor + Carrier.CARRIER_LENGTH);
            // Updates the char array
            for (int y = yCor; y < yCor + Carrier.CARRIER_LENGTH; y++) {
                selfGrid[y][xCor] = SHIP;
            }
            isShipPlaced = true;
        }

        else if (shipOrientation == HORIZONTAL && xCor + Carrier.CARRIER_LENGTH < BattleshipSystem.GRID_LENGTH) {
            playerShips[0] = new Carrier(xCor, yCor, xCor + Carrier.CARRIER_LENGTH, yCor);
            for (int x = xCor; x < xCor + Carrier.CARRIER_LENGTH; x++) {
                selfGrid[yCor][x] = SHIP;
            }
            isShipPlaced = true;
        }
    }
    while (!isShipPlaced);
    // Use of "do-while" loop in order to continuously randomize coordinates until they are valid and in bounds of the grid array
}

This is the code I've written to place a "carrier" ship on the grid, I wrote a similar method to create a "battleship" on the grid but what ended up happening was that the ships overlapped each other or were next to each other (which I did not want) but I do not know how exactly I should error check to ensure that my conditions are met.
Also, I'm really concerned as this method is already extremely long, I do not want to write multiple methods for every type of ship.

Just check if the ship overlaps an earlier ship (or is directly adjacent to one) and in this case re-roll until you find a free spot? Best place the bigger ships first, then it should not be a problem to fit them all on the board.

Did you try Googling for java battleships game in order to see how others have done it?

The function is called placeCarrier but it is doing 2 things: creating a carrier and placing it. Maybe have 2 different functions: one that creates a ship, and one that places it (checking for collisions). Have the base ship class have a member size that you can use in these functions.

Your coordinates should start from 0, not 1. This will allow you to index the first row and column of your grid, both of which start from 0. Also, instead of (int) (Math.random() * 9) you can use Random.nextInt(int bound).

Let's go by parts, there is no “right” way to do this, you do not provide much information (you have not taken the relevant decisions), even so, I will allow you to make a suggestion, make a simple Ship class, something like this:
    class Ship {
    
       int size;
       int id;
       static int number = 0;
       Atack atackType;
    
       public Ship() {
          id = number ++;
       }
    
       // getters and setters
    }
    
    class Carrier extends Ship {
    
       int size = 5;;
       Atack atackType = Atack.airAtack;
    
       public Ship() {
          super();
       }    
    }

and leave the management and location of the ships to the Board class (in my example is an array), since the attacks will probably be directed to Cell objects.
To know if it can be placed in the determined position, we must verify that all the positions it is going to occupy are empty, as well as all the surrounding ones, graphically it would be something like this:
// #######  
// #55555#  
// #######  

being “5” parts of the ship and “#” the surrounding squares
The first method is responsible for placing the ships on the board, the other methods are auxiliary to this.
      // get the size of the board and an array with the ships
    String[][] locateBoats( int side, String ships[][] ) {
       String board[][] = new String[ side ][ side ];
       fill( board );
       int which = 0;
       Random Ram = new Random();
       int size = board[ 0 ].length;
    
          // each row of the matrix, represents a boat
       while( which < ships.length ) {
    
            // we determine if it goes horizontally or vertically
          int direction = Ram.nextInt( 2 );
          int sizeBoat = ships[ which ].length;
    
            // we generate the initial position within the allowed range
          int x = Ram.nextInt( size - sizeBoat +1 );
          int y = Ram.nextInt( size - sizeBoat +1 );
    
             // “sizeI” and “sizeK” take the value of the side of the rectangle we 
             // need to verify, for height and width respectively.
             // “upI” and “upK” are used to know (at the time of printing the ship, 
             // in which direction to go, “k” and “i” are the positions from which to // start iterating. 
             // it starts iterating
          
          int sizeI = 3, sizeK = 3, k = x -1, i = y -1, upK = 0, upI = 0;  
          
             // this part of the code is in charge of instantiating the values of the variables, 
             // depending on the direction, if we are in horizontal, the height 
             // should be “3”, unless “y” is zero, in which case it should be “2”, 
             // the width should be equal to the length of the ship plus “2”, unless “x” 
             // is “0” in which case it should be ship length + “1”. 
        
          if( direction == 0 ) { // horizontal
             sizeK += boat size - 1;
             upK = 1;
          }
          else {
             sizeI += sizeBoat - 1;
             upI = 1;
          }
          if( x == 0 ) {
             k = x;
             sizeK -= 1;
          }
          if( y == 0 ) {
             i = y;
             sizeI -= 1;
          }
     
          boolean reset = false;
            
             // we use this variable as memory to store the value of “k”.
          int mem = k;
            // we create the stopping conditions of the for
          int conditionI = i + sizeI;
          int conditionK = k + sizeK;
          for( ; i < conditionI && i < size; i++ ) {
             k = mem;
             for( ; k < conditionK && k < size; k++ ) {    
    
                   // if the position is not empty, we set “reset” to “true” to 
                   // prevent it from recording the ship and exit the internal for.
                if( ! board[ i ][ k ].equals( “ ” )) { 
                   restart = true;
                   break;
                }               
             }
          }      
          
             // if it did not find occupied positions, it enters the if, takes the value of 
             // the letter of the ship, and modifies the value contained in the positions
          if( !restart ) {
             String letter = ships[ which ][ 0 ];
             for( i = y, k = x; i < y + sizeBoat && k < x + sizeBoat; i += subei, k += subek ) {
                board[ i ][ k ] = letter;
             }
             which++;
          }
       }
       return board;
    }   
    
    void fill( String array[][] ) {
       for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
          for( int j = 0; j < array.length; j++ ) {
             array[ i ][ j ] = “ ”;
          }
       }
    }
    
    String ships[][] = {
       { “5”, “5”, “5”, “5”, “5” }, { “4”, “4”, “4”, “4”, },
       { “4”, “4”, “4”, “4”, }, { “3”, “3”, “3” }, { “3”, “3”, “3” },
       { “3”, “3”, “3” }, { “2”, “2” }, { “2”, “2” }, { “2”, “2” }, { “2”, “2” }
    };

Note: it is very likely that if you use a small board size (in relation to the number and length of ships) you will enter an infinite loop... be careful, or add a limit to the iterations of the while, with the matrix of ships that we have above, a “15x15” board does not give problems, as we shrink the side...
